# Why is Windows Update telling me to install Internet Explorer 10 even though it is already installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, internet-explorer-10

I have a Windows 7 laptop. For some reason, Windows Update keeps telling me to install Internet Explorer 10 for Windows 7 even though it is already installed (downloaded from Microsoft website). Whenever I try and install it from Windows Update in order to get rid of it, I receive error 9C48. What is the problem and how do I solve it? (I've noticed several entries for similar problems online, but those are all for Internet Explorer 9).

As I said in the comments, my system keeps trying to install the same update when it is shutting down, only failing with the same error. It is hogging my shut down button and wasting time during shutdown.

**Update:** I just went and installed Internet Explorer 11 from the Windows website. However, Windows Update continues to offer me Internet Explorer 10. How can I tell it that the update is in fact installed so that it instead starts offering me updates?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling IE10 then reinstalling through Windows Update?

Comment: @Moses I will try that.

Comment: Have you restarted and then run Windows Update?

Comment: @MDMoore313 I have restarted several times. It is also worth mentioning that my system keeps trying to install it when it is shutting down, and failing with the same error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I installed Internet Explorer 11, I just went and hid the Internet Explorer 10 update. This way, I no longer receive notifications of the update as I already have a newer version installed.